# Invalid folder location on JAR export (Spring property)

Tags: java, spring, build, jar, export

I need to export a Java project into an executable file, for example a JAR.
The project uses a Spring XML context file to instantiate a bean and injects it with the following value: "src/main/resources/", which corresponds to the location of a CSV file.

When I generate the JAR, the "src/main/resources" folder is not part of the JAR, and therefore the execution fails because the beans can't load the required CSV file.

What is the best way to deal with this issue?
And what would be the best way to generate the executable JAR? Exporting from Eclipse? Maven Assembly plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Maven generally deploys content in "src/main/resources" to the WEB-INF directory of your webapp.

Comment: Hi fred02138. This is a basic Java project, not a webapp. When Maven generates this JAR file, all the files from the resource folder are placed in the "root" of the JAR.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Maven `jar` project, the `package` target will generate a jar file with /src/main/resources in the root of the jar with all subfolders extending from there.

Eclipse can do the same thing if you put /src/main/resources on your build classpath.

Either way you have to tell Spring to find the context xml file on the classpath, assuming its directly in /src/main/resources and not a subfolder.

When you tell Spring to build the BeanFactory (or ApplicationContext or whatever) don't use `/src/main/resources/spring-context.xml` as the filename. Use `spring-context.xml` and tell it its on the classpath with something like `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring-context.xml")`. Or you can use `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context.xml")`

When you add /src/main/resources to your eclipse classpath, you can run in Eclipse or in the jar.

Comment: Lee, I generated the JAR with Maven. However, the src/main/resources is not created. Instead, the resource files are placed in the root of the JAR. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Lee, yes, the src/main/resources folder is on the classpath and I am loading the Spring Context file without problems. The problem is that the bean is instantiated with a property with the following value: "src/main/resources". This allows the bean to know where it should load the CSV file from. I guess I should change the way the program looks up this CSV file?

Comment: Yes. Load it as a resource from the classpath.